# Pass variable value to URL

Tags: php

I am using below code to get paramteres from the URL.

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post" role="search">
    <select name="seme" id="seme">
        <option value="sem1">Semester-1</option>
        <option value="sem2">Semester-2</option>
        <option value="sem3">Semester-3</option>
        <option value="sem4">Semester-4</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="find" id="find" placeholder="Enter worksheet / file name..." />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme">Search</button>
</form>

<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // collect value of input field
    $name = $_REQUEST['find'];
    $sem = $_REQUEST['seme']; 
    if (empty($name)) {
        echo "Name is empty";
    } else {
        echo $name; echo $seme;
    }
}
?>
```

But the problem is that I am getting only value of **textbox**.I want to get value of select box as well.What should I do ? Or where am I lacking ???

Thanks !!!

Comment: How do you know you don't get the selectbox value? did you echo it?

Comment: Thanks for that question !! Solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use $_POST[] method to get value instead of $_REQUEST[]? Try $_POST['seme']

Answer (score 0):

You are printing different variable name for selectbox value you are getting value in **`$sem`**
and printing **`$seme`**.

use this:

```
if ($_SERVER ["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // collect value of input field
    $name = $_REQUEST ['find'];
    $seme = $_REQUEST ['seme'];
    if (empty ( $name )) {
        echo "Name is empty";
    } else {
        echo $name . "<br/>";
        echo $seme;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["find"])&&isset($_POST["seme"])) {
    // collect value of input field
    $name = $_POST["find"];
    $sem = $_POST["seme"]; 
    echo $name; echo $seme;
}else{
    if (!isset($_POST["find"])){
       echo "Name is empty";
    }
    if (!isset($_POST["seme"])){
       echo "Semester type is empty";
    }
}
?>
```